# How to embed Google Custom Search in React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-custom-search

I need to embed a JS widget in a React app. Is there a way to do it?

The JS widget is Google Custom Search:

```js
  (function() {
    var cx = '111:xxx';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
```

```html
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
  (function() {
    var cx = '111:xxx';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
}
```

and use

```
<div class="gcse-searchbox" data-resultsUrl="http://www.example.com"
data-newWindow="true" data-queryParameterName="search" />`
```

instead of `<gcse:search></gcse:search>` according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#html5)

Comment: What about cleaning up once the component unmouints? Will this work properly when mouning such a component again?

Answer (score 0):

To expanciate on what @MiguelSlv wrote...

Place:

```
(function() {
    var cx = '111:xxx';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })(),
```

In your App.js file. And place:

```
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=111:xxx">
```

in any your site's body section where you want the search box.