# Google Custom Search Engine does not appear in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-custom-search

I followed both the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#html5), and the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54516079/5434087), on SO. But the input field just wouldn't load on localhost. It does however if I just add it into an index.html file.

```html
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=123456">
</script>
<div class="gcse-search"></div>
```

Does anybody know what might cause it?

Things I tried:

1. Added it to my page as displayed above.
2. Added the `script` tag separately into the `head` tag.
3. Added the script as a function into the `ComponentDidMount`

Comment: The accepted answer's solution works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-cascading-select-forked-5nzssf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I figured out, that it needs to be served statically, but I don't know why. Does anybody have an answer to that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to embed Google Custom Search in React App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53710449/how-to-embed-google-custom-search-in-react-app)

Comment: Nope, I literally linked it in my question.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how the example in codesandbox should work. It's using useState as useEffect

Comment: Haha, you're right! Fixed. Anyway, the "Does this answer your question?" nonsense gets added automatically when you mark as dupe and I was too lazy to edit it. The point is: I know you linked to it but the proposed solution of adding the script to <head> does work.

Comment: Actually, it started working! Thank you very much!